# Using cURL with a username and password?

Tags: curl, credentials

I want to access a URL which requires a username/password. I'd like to try accessing it with curl. Right now I'm doing something like:

```
curl http://api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123
```

I get an error. I guess I need to specify a username and password along with the above command.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 924):

Use the `-u` flag to include a username, and curl will prompt for a password:

```
curl -u username http://example.com
```

You can also include the password in the command, but then your password will be visible in bash history:

```
curl -u username:password http://example.com
```

Comment: Note that if you do this from the console the password will remain in the history which is ... wrong. You should specify just -u user and CURL will ask you for the password in no-echo mode.

Comment: note that embedding the user:pass in the URL will fail if you have a exported http_proxy or https_proxy

Comment: @CristianVrabie Technically correct, but incorrect if you're running it from an automated script that doesn't allow prompts. Would be curious about a solution to that problem.

Comment: What is a more secure way of doing that if I want to `curl` in a script? There's no option for me to enter the password while the script is running because I'm `curl`ing in a loop.

Comment: @OmarOthman if you're running curl from a script, the credentials (obviously) won't end up in your history, but they'll be visible in ps(1).  fix: `print -- '-u username:password' > somewhere && curl -K somewhere http://...`

Comment: You could put credentials in [ENV variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps) for scripting

Comment: Does this command still work if the password input field has id="whatever" instead of id="PASSWORD"?

Comment: You should also make sure that the file you create is ONLY accessible by you.  Most system by default give read access to world.

Comment: @Jay Environment variables will be evaluated before command execution. Password will be still visible in ps output.

Comment: @RobertVažan very true

Comment: Not to belabor the point but I believe my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894407/758174 i.e. using `--netrc-file`) is more secure.  It keeps the password out of history, ps, your script, etc.  That is the only form I use in all my scripts and for all authenticated usages of `curl`.

Comment: I'm using this for development of an Elasticsearch cluster. The default password is `changeme`, so I'm not worried it'll be visible in my history, as it's currently only local. Once our CI is set up for elastic, we'll switch to a more secure way of querying elasticsearch.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous. Possible matches
include: -UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.

Comment: @NaveenDennis sounds like PowerShell's `curl` doesn't have feature parity with the original one.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672760/powershells-invoke-restmethod-equivalent-of-curl-u-basic-authentication

Comment: While the password still shows in the console history, it does not show in the output of `ps` : [How does curl protect a password from appearing in ps output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339) (just a fun fact, not trying to give the idea that I am not not claiming you should not prefer the netrc approach...)

Comment: If you do want to pass the password in the command line, this may be an interesting read : [How to remove a single line from history? -> Preventative measures](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49216/101404)

Comment: If you have an automated script, couldn't you follow up the command with `history -d` to delete the previous command from the history?

Answer (score 357):

It is safer to do:

```
curl --netrc-file my-password-file http://example.com
```

...as passing a plain user/password string on the command line, is a bad idea.

The format of the password file is (as per `man curl`):

```
machine <example.com> login <username> password <password>
```

Note:

1. Machine name must *not* include `https://` or similar! Just the hostname.
2. The words '`machine`', '`login`', and '`password`' are just keywords; the actual information is the stuff after those keywords.

Comment: Yeah, that keeps the password out of the process listing and command history. Far preferable way to do this, and only a little more work :)

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer; passwords on the command-line are a horrible practice. (And this is a widely known fact.)

Comment: You can also use the flag `-K <file>` or `--config <file>` to receive curl flags via file or standard input.  (Warning: not to be confused with `-k` or `--insecure`!)

Comment: This curl method keeps credentials out of the history and process status, but leaves username and password in cleartext in the my-password-file creating another attack vector - worse than than having info in the history file: bash, for example, automatically restricts permissions of the history file.  A similar problem arises if using environment variables with e.g. a script to set the username/password. If the script isn't secure, neither are the credentials.

Comment: Can you provide an actual example `.netrc` file? I'm able to use cURL with username/pw but not with the file, as you've written this answer.

Comment: `http` and `password` is a bad idea, use `https`

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused I disagree, it's much better to use a cleartext `.netrc` file with appropriately strict permissions, so only *your* user can read it, than other mechanisms (e.g. command line args) that let *other* users read the information.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'my-password-file'

Comment: @NaveenDennis I guess you're using the PowerShell "curl" cmdlet.  But recent versions of Windows 10 include "real" curl executable, so you could try running your command from cmd, or running `curl.exe`.

Comment: Is there a way to debug using --netrc-file, because nothing is happening for me and I don't know why. Using the -u flag with curl produced immediate results but I don't want to use it if it's less secure.

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused raises a valid concern, but it can (counterintuetively) be solved using Process Substitution on shells that have echo as a built-in as follows: `curl --netrc-file <(echo "machine example.com login scott passowrd tiger") http://example.com`. This _looks_ like it will still leak the password in process listings, but as no process is created for the built-in echo, it should be safe. Just don´t try to do this using /bin/echo

Comment: On *NIX machines, touch ~/.netrc; chmod go-rwx ~/.netrc, put your creds in that file, then use just "-n" on the curl command line. Note that you run chmod BEFORE adding content to the file. If you are still using an archaic system, like Windows, you might not have such permission settings (I have not used Windows for 11 years).

Comment: .netrc file syntax: `machine <hostname> login <login> password <password>` per line. https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc

Answer (score 94):

Or the same thing but different syntax

```
curl http://username:password@api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123
```

Comment: I use that syntax, because can be used in a lot of more situations. Like from a Windows cmd with no cURL and no wGet, using `start "" "http://username:password@api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123"`. It can be launched from anywhere. That also applies to ftp logins ;D

Comment: You need to URL encode the username & password to use funny characters

Comment: I know that most people know not to send passwords (or even user names) in the URL like this example as it is easy to sniff. With that said; I don't unrecommend it but use only when you know what you are doing.

Comment: This is suuuuuper archaic and should _not_ be used. This is from the FTP days :o

Comment: Curious, is it secure, for example, using user/pass directly in url even if used https?

Comment: Unfortunately, this leaves the password visible in the process list.

Comment: @MarkRibau it does not show in the process list if you use the `-u` argument. neat trick from curl :-). see [How does curl protect a password from appearing in ps output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339)

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen That mechanism of curl is a nice work-around for incautious script authors, but not fully safe. Using "-K" is much safer. See the second comment of the very question you yourself linked to.

Answer (score 69):

You can also just send the user name by writing:

```
curl -u USERNAME http://server.example
```

Curl will then ask you for the password, and the password will not be visible on the screen (or if you need to copy/paste the command).

Answer (score 41):

To securely pass the password in a script (i.e. prevent it from showing up with ps auxf or logs) you can do it with the -K- flag (read config from stdin) and a heredoc:

```
curl --url url -K- <<< "--user user:password"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the `--config` option (-K)... possibly a better solution would be to put "--user user:password" into a file and simply `-K the file` so you have only one copy of the password rather a copy in every script. Much easier to secure a single file.

Comment: Similar option, where only the password is in the file: `cat "${password_filepath}" | sed -e "s/^/-u ${username}:/" | curl --url "${url}" -K-`. I had to put `-K-` before the url for old macOS bash, YMMV.

Comment: This looks like the idea solution for use with Jenkins.

Comment: No need to use sed if the password is in a file: `echo "-u user:$(cat passwordfile)"|curl -K- url`

Comment: @Martin - make the file ~/.netrc and use -n

Answer (score 20):

Usually CURL command refer to as

```
curl https://example.com\?param\=ParamValue -u USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

if you don't have any password or want to skip command prompt to demand for password simple leave the password section blank.

i.e. `curl https://example.com\?param\=ParamValue -u USERNAME:`

Comment: NOTE: Password would be visible in shell history and process list.

Answer (score 14):

```
curl -X GET -u username:password  {{ http://www.example.com/filename.txt }} -O
```

Comment: NOTE: Password would be visible in shell history and process list.

Answer (score 11):

Other answers have suggested netrc to specify username and password, based on what I've read, I agree.  Here are some syntax details:

https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-netrc.html

Like other answers, I would like to stress the need to pay attention to security regarding this question.

Although I am not an expert, I found these links insightful:

https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-passwords.html

To summarize:

Using the **encrypted versions of the protocols** (HTTPS vs HTTP) (FTPS vs FTP) can help avoid Network Leakage.

Using **netrc** can help avoid Command Line Leakage.

To go a step further, it seems you can also encrypt the netrc files using gpg

https://brandur.org/fragments/gpg-curl

With this your credentials are not "at rest" (stored) as plain text.

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 11):

pretty easy, do the below:

```
curl -X GET/POST/PUT <URL> -u username:password
```

Comment: There is no requirement of security on the question

Comment: NOTE: Password would be visible in shell history and process list

Answer (score 10):

To let the password least not pop up in your `.bash_history`:

```
curl -u user:$(cat .password-file) http://example-domain.tld
```

Comment: In this case, the password will still end up in the process list, e.g. it is visible to somebody doing `ps auxw |grep curl` at the right time.  Similarly, the password will be logged if run via `sudo`

Comment: With this method the password is then present in a file (.password-file) which may be more insecure than the .bash history. The good part about this, is that it is only the password - the URL and username are not leaked in the .password-file.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same need in bash (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and the commands provided in the answers failed to work in my case. I had to use:

```
curl -X POST -F 'username="$USER"' -F 'password="$PASS"' "http://api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123"
```

Double quotes in the `-F` arguments are only needed if you're using variables, thus from the command line `... -F 'username=myuser' ...` will be fine.

**Relevant Security Notice: as [Mr. Mark Ribau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150794/mark-ribau) points in comments this command shows the password ($PASS variable, expanded) in the processlist!**

Comment: Looks like this still shows the value of $PASS in the process list?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does.

Comment: I am getting `curl: option -F: is badly used here`. curl 7.58. What is your version?

Answer (score 6):

You can use command like,

```
curl -u user-name -p http://www.example.com/path-to-file/file-name.ext > new-file-name.ext
```

Then HTTP password will be triggered.

Reference:
http://www.asempt.com/article/how-use-curl-http-password-protected-site

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: -p stands for --proxytunnel - misleading, but otherwise correct: "-u ... If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password." https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 6):

The safest way to pass credentials to curl is to be prompted to insert them. This is what happens when passing the username as suggested earlier (`-u USERNAME`).

*But what if you can't pass the username that way?* 
For instance the username might need to be part of the url and only the password be part of a json payload.

**tl;dr:** 
This is how to use curl safely in this case:

```
read -p "Username: " U; read -sp "Password: " P; curl --request POST -d "{\"password\":\"${P}\"}" https://example.com/login/${U}; unset P U
```

`read` will prompt for both username and password from the command line, and store the submitted values in two variables that can be references in subsequent commands and finally unset.

I'm gonna elaborate on why the other solutions are not ideal.

**Why are environment variables unsafe**

1. Access and exposure mode of the content of an environment variable, can not be tracked (ps -eww ) since the environment is implicitly available to a process
2. Often apps grab the whole environment and log it for debugging or monitoring purposes (sometimes on log files plaintext on disk, especially after an app crashes)
3. Environment variables are passed down to child processes (therefore breaking the principle of least privilege)
4. Maintaining them is an issue: new engineers don't know they are there, and are not aware of requirements around them - e.g., not to pass them to sub-processes - since they're not enforced or documented.

**Why is it unsafe to type it into a command on the command line directly**
Because your secret then ends up being visible by any other user running `ps -aux` since that lists commands submitted for each currently running process.
Also because your secrte then ends up in the bash history (once the shell terminates).

**Why is it unsafe to include it in a local file**
Strict POSIX access restriction on the file can mitigate the risk in this scenario. However, it is still a file on your file system, unencrypted at rest.

Comment: It seems that this method would still show the password in the process list?

Comment: The other answer also miss to use the "read" command. That hits the essence I landed on this page. Why not add the follwoing line to your post:

"read -p "Username: " U;  curl -u "$U" <URL>; unset U"

Answer (score 5):

Plain and simply put the most secure way would be to use environment variables to store/retrieve your credentials. Thus a curl command like:

```
curl -Lk -XGET -u "${API_USER}:${API_HASH}" -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -- "http://api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123"
```

Would then call your restful api and pass the http `WWW_Authentication` header with the Base64 encoded values of `API_USER` and `API_HASH`. The `-Lk` just tells curl to follow http 30x redirects and to use insecure tls handling (ie ignore ssl errors). While the double `--` is just bash syntax sugar to stop processing command line flags. Furthermore, the `-b cookies.txt` and `-c cookies.txt` flags handle cookies with `-b` sending cookies and `-c` storing cookies locally.

The manual has more [examples of authentication](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication) methods.

Comment: Bear in mind that using "-Lk" can open you up to man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks, so use caution with that option.

Comment: This doesn't work... since bash expands those variables for you, the expansion appears in the process listing.

Answer (score 4):

In some API maybe it does not work (like rabbitmq).

there is alternative:

```
curl http://username:password@example.com

curl http://admin:123456@example.com
```

**also the above format is usable in browsers.**

Answer (score 4):

You can use gpg encrypted netrc file with curl like so:

```
netrc_file="$HOME/netrc.gpg"
curl --netrc-file <(gpg -d $netrc_file) https://...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is MUCH more than the OP asked for, but since this is a top result for securely passing passwords to `curl`, I'm adding these solutions here for others who arrive here searching for that.

---

NOTE: `-s` arg for `read` command is not POSIX, and so is not available everywhere, so it won't be used below. We will use `stty -echo` and `stty echo` instead.

NOTE: All bash variables below could instead be declared as locals if in a function, rather than unsetting.

NOTE: `perl` is pretty generally available on all systems I've tried due to it being a dependency for many things, whereas `ruby` and `python` are not, so using `perl` here. If you can guarantee `ruby`/`python` where you're doing this, you can replace the `perl` command with their equivalent.

NOTE: Tested in `bash` 3.2.57 on macOS 10.14.4. Some small translation may be required for other shells/installs.

---

Securely prompt a user for a (reusable) password to pass to curl. Particularly useful if you need to call curl multiple times.

For modern shells, where `echo` is a built-in (check via `which echo`):

```
url='https://example.com'
printf "Username: "
read username
printf "Password: "
stty -echo  # disables echoing user input, POSIX equivalent for 'read -s'
read pass
printf "\n" # we need to move the line ahead
stty echo   # re-enable echoing user input
echo ${pass} | sed -e "s/^/-u ${username}:/" | curl --url "${url}" -K-
unset username
unset pass
```

For older shells, where `echo` is something like `/bin/echo` (where whatever it echos can be seen in the process list):
**THIS VERSION CANNOT REUSE THE PASSWORD**, see lower down instead.

```
url='https://example.com'
printf "Username: "
read username
printf "Password: "
stty -echo  # disables echoing user input, POSIX equivalent for 'read -s'
perl -e '
    my $val=<STDIN>;
    chomp $val;
    print STDERR "\n";  # we need to move the line ahead, but not send a newline down the pipe
    print $val;
' | sed -e "s/^/-u ${username}:/" | curl --url "${url}" -K-
stty echo   # re-enable echoing user input
unset username
```

---

If you happen to need to store the password temporarily to a file, to re-use it for multiple commands before clearing it (say because you're using functions for code re-use and don't want to repeat code and can't pass the value around via echo). (Yes, these are a little contrived looking in this form not being functions in different libraries; I tried to reduce them to the minimum code needed to show it.)

When echo is built-in (this is especially contrived, since echo is a built-in, but provided for completeness):

```
url='https://example.com'
filepath="$(mktemp)"  # random path, only readable by current user
printf "Username: "
read username
printf "Password: "
stty -echo  # disables echoing user input, POSIX equivalent for 'read -s'
read pass
echo "${pass}" > "${filepath}"
unset pass
printf "\n" # we need to move the line ahead
stty echo   # re-enable echoing user input

cat "${filepath}" | sed -e "s/^/-u ${username}:/" | curl --url "${url}" -K-

rm "${filepath}"  # don't forget to delete the file when done!!
unset username
```

When echo is something like `/bin/echo`:

```
url='https://example.com'
filepath="$(mktemp)"  # random path, only readable by current user
printf "Username: "
read username
printf "Password: "
stty -echo  # disables echoing user input, POSIX equivalent for 'read -s'
$(perl -e '
    my $val=<STDIN>;
    chomp $val;
    open(my $fh, ">", $ARGV[0]) or die "Could not open file \"$ARGV[0]\" $\!";
    print $fh $val;
    close $fh;
' "$filepath")
printf "\n" # we need to move the line ahead
stty echo   # re-enable echoing user input

cat "${filepath}" | sed -e "s/^/-u ${username}:/" | curl --url "${url}" -K-

rm "${filepath}"  # don't forget to delete the file when done!!
unset username
```

Comment: "don't forget to delete the file when done" - Kiss of death, an error in the script could leave that file in the system. If you trust the "readable only by current user" then you should trust the .netrc file with rw only by the user.

Answer (score 2):

If your server supports `Basic` auth, you could do:

```
printf 'header="Authorization: Basic %s"' "$(base64 --wrap=0 credentials)"|
curl --config - https://example.org
```

`credentials` would be the file where you store the username and password in the form `username:password`.

Benefits of this solution:

- No escaping of special characters necessary
- Works with any password, even when it contains spaces, quotation marks, backslashes or other special characters, therefore it can also be used securely in scripts where you don’t control the input
- In shells with builtin `printf`, the login data does not show up in the process list

If your shell does not have `printf` as a builtin command, you could do something like this to avoid the login data appearing in the process list:

```
{ printf 'header="Authorization: Basic '; base64 --wrap=0 credentials; printf '"'; }|
curl --config - https://example.org
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a system that has Gnome keyring app a solution that avoids exposing the password directly  is to use [gkeyring.py](https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring) to extract the password from the keyring:

```
server=server.example.com
file=path/to/my/file
user=my_user_name
pass=$(gkeyring.py -k login -tnetwork -p user=$user,server=$server -1)

curl -u $user:$pass ftps://$server/$file -O
```

Comment: NOTE: Password would be visible in process list. (And history if this isn't part of a script.)

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure what is the authentication type.

If it is digest authentication , http header is:

```sh
GET /xxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.3.142
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="admin@51200304-49-test", nonce="5.1722929000077545", uri="/xxxxxxxxxxx", response="52d30eba90820f2c4fa4d3292a4a7bbc", cnonce="f11900fe0906e3899e0cc431146512bb", qop=auth, nc=00000001
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

you can use `--digest` option :

```sh
    curl  --digest -u 'username:password' 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Can you add why you would need the `--digest` option?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed a prompt where the user can enter their credentials.

The most simplistic way to get a prompt for username and password would be the following one-liner:

```
read -p "Username: " U ; curl -u "$U" <URL> ; unset U
```

The `read` command prompts for the username. The `-u "$U"` parameter tells curl to try to authenticate with the username `$U` and prompt for the password.

As a bonus the password will only be visible to curl and won't end up in any log or history.

The man page of curl has more details about different authentication modes:
https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

I also like the approach the user "iammyr" takes. It can cover cases where the authentication algorithm of cURL fails:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56130884/1239715

Answer (score 0):

This has been mentioned in several comments....

```
% touch ~/.netrc
% chmod go-rwx ~/.netrc
```

Edit ~/.netrc using your "favorite editor" (apparently, if you don't use your favorite editor, it won't work and you won't cross the Bridge of Death) and add lines similar to:

```
machine  <machine name> login <login name>  password <password>
```

For example

```
machine  monty  login sirrobin  password african-swallow
```

This will keep the credentials out of command history and the process list, eliminate the need to enter the password by hand so your script can run autonomously, much simpler to use than having to specify a filename.

It does, however, leave the text in a file "at rest" (interesting term), so you have to rely on your system to enforce access restrictions (does that eliminate Windows?) and also expect that if root access (or your account) is compromised, then so is the content of .netrc.

The solutions that use gpg to decrypt an encrypted .netrc file push the credential requirement to gpg, so you have to be there when the script runs to provide the password or the password is provided by some other means, perhaps using a file similar to .netrc? ... and you have the same problem.