# PHP - Access to a password protected page

Tags: php, password-protection, http-authentication

I would just like to find a way in PHP (a link, a button, etc.) to give the user the possibility to open a (http-authentication-based) password protected page.

I already tried with a simple href containing the link to:

```
http://username:password@domain
```

but it seems it does not work anymore in current browsers.

Is there a way to do this? It seems a very trivial problem, but actually I still  have not found a way.

Thank you.

Comment: yeah create a login page

Comment: Maybe [CURL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2594908/1459926) ?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the `username:password` scheme won't work accross all browsers. What you can do - if you don't mind a script based solution - is to establish authentication via AJAX first, then present the user a normal link.

Idea outlined:

1. A client side script establishes authentication via AJAX.
2. Once this succeeds, you present the appropriate link to the user.
3. The user's client automatically submits the credentials generated in step 1 once the user follows the link.

See [this How-To for example](http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this should not work. Possible security issues that modern browsers are trying to avoid.

But to get this done, you could use

```
    <script>
function foo(){
window.location = "http://username:password@domain";
}
</script>

    <a onclick='foo()'>Click here</a>
```

Comment: Yes, as you said, modern browser does not allow that anymore for security issues.