# Grab xml data from website with password

Tags: php, xml

I want to grab data from a website say `www.example.com/stations` with XML output:

```
<stations>
    <station>
        <name>Loppersum</name>
        <code>LP</code>
        <country>NL</country>
        <lat>53.334713</lat>
        <long>6.7472625</long>
        <alias>false</alias>
    </station>
    <station>
         <name>Ludinghausen</name>
         <code>ELDH</code>
         <country>D</country>
         <lat>51.76184</lat>
         <long>7.43165</long>
         <alias>true</alias>
    </station>
</stations>
```

But the url is protected by a password and username (I have that).

I thought that I can use the cURL function, but i never used it before.
Can I store the data also as a object?

**EDIT:**
It is a HTTP Authorization and I use **PHP**

Comment: There's a similar answer about HTTP auth and cURL here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2140445/209585

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You didn't specify what kind of login scheme is in use.</strike>

If you're up against HTTP authorization, you can simply use the `-u` argument with curl. See this answer: [Using cURL with a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

If you're up against cookie authorization, it gets a bit more complicated. You'll most likely need to act as a web browser and "login" to the website, and then perform your request. Both requests will need access to a cookie jar/file that you provide to curl.

**Edit:**
The author indicated that this is HTTP authorization using PHP.

The solution would be to use PHP's `SimpleXMLElement` to get the XML object. You can use Curl to download the XML data and pass it into the constructor, or you can have `SimpleXMLElement` do it for you.

Try this:

```
$user = 'someuser';
$pass = 'somepass';
$url  = "http://$someuser:$somepass@example.com/stations";
$obj  = new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, TRUE);

echo $obj->movie[0]->title; // example
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is an HTTP authorization

Comment: Providing the `-u` argument should work, then. As for the object, I'm not quite sure. Is this being requested from the shell?

Comment: No, I do it with php, so not with the commandprompt

Comment: In PHP, you can use the `SimpleXMLElement` to get what you want. Once you get the data, pass it to the constructor, like this: `$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($response);`. You can also tell it that `$response` is a URL instead of XML data by setting the third parameter to `TRUE`. More info: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.construct.php