# How to succesfully pass Jira WebSudo through API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I would like to list all permission schemes via API.
On premise JIRA v 8.13.7
I'm calling endpoint `rest/api/2/permissionscheme`.

The result is `<status><status-code>401</status-code><message>This resource requires WebSudo.</message></status>`

First I authorize myself via cookie. I've included also valid call (search for a user).

I found this answer
[Jira ServiceDesk User Creation - This resource requires WebSudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60511082/jira-servicedesk-user-creation-this-resource-requires-websudo)

First option is using cookies. Doesn't work, or I don't understand. 
Second option is not available for me.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer
};

client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jira/");

var content = new StringContent($"{{ \"username\": \"xxx\", \"password\": \"xxx\" }}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("rest/auth/1/session", content);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (responseContent != null)
{
    responseContent.Dump();
}

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var jiraCookie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JiraCookie>(responseContent);

var cookie = new Cookie
{
    Name = jiraCookie.session.name,
    Value = jiraCookie.session.value,
    Domain = client.BaseAddress.Host
};

cookieContainer.Add(cookie);

//This call is OK. Http Status Code 200. There is a valid JSON in the response
response = await client.GetAsync("rest/api/2/user?username=yyy");
responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//This call returns 401 and response content xml ..."This resource requires WebSudo"
response = await client.GetAsync("rest/api/2/permissionscheme");
responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```