# While using REST API in Powershell for TFS 2015.2 how to secure your password without using it in the script

Tags: rest, api, encryption, powershell-2.0, tfs-2015

While I use the method mentioned in this thread [PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod equivalent of curl -u (Basic Authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672760/powershells-invoke-restmethod-equivalent-of-curl-u-basic-authentication) **I could get connected to REST API without a 401 error.**

However currently I am giving my password in Plain Text.

I want a way to use a Hash of my password and then use it in the script.

The script then should be able to decrypt it too. But I don't want others who have access to the script, be able to decrypt it.

So I don't want to expose the decryption algorithm as well to any.

*Proposed method I am thinking of:*
**Combine existing HASH algorithms in a mixed random way (by feeding the HASH of one algorithm to another) which only I know and then have a custom Powershell function/cmdlet/whatever in the script which knows to decrypt.**

Is there a simpler and better way?

Before I try the proposed method I would like to hear from others on any better ways.

Entire script is as below.

---

```bsh
$User = "domain\userName"
$uri = "https://TeamProjectCollectionURI/TeamProjectName/_apis/build/builds"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PasswordWhichContains$asWell' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$credential)))
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json
$response
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a username and password (masked as a *secret variable*) through PowerShell into a **PSCredential** object and use the **-Credential** switch when invoking the REST method:

```
$securePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force   $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword)       
$releaseresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Credential $credential -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri
```

More detail info please refer this blog: [VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/)

Comment: Dear Patrick,

Thanks for your comment.

$Password is a variable and the actual password needs to be given in the script itself right?

I don't want to expose my password in the script.

Comment: I tried it.. It works.. I tried to store the encrypted string in the script and use it.. But facing issue with it..

However when I store it in a file and then read it in the script it works.. This link is the reference http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/

I am trying to use a secure approach with -securekey option as explained part-2 of the above mentioned blog..

Comment: Sometimes I will get "401  Unauthorized" exception, so I changed the script into `Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your password to encrypted string and use the encrypted string in your PowerShell script.

Convert to encrypted string:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Yourpassword" -AsPlainText -Force

$encryptedPwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $securePassword

Write-Host $encryptedPwd
```

Record the generated encrypted string and use it in your script.

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Encrypted String"
```

Comment: Sure I will give this a try and let you know