# Curl Error: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to connect (in PowerShell) via 
**curl**
but with no success.

Below is the following code I've inserting in order to establish the connection:

```
  curl -u <USER>:<PASSWORD> https://something.com
```

but got the error:

```
  Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'u' is ambiguous. 
  Possible matches include: -UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.
```

So, I tried to look for a solution at SO, such as:

[PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod equivalent of curl -u (Basic Authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672760/powershells-invoke-restmethod-equivalent-of-curl-u-basic-authentication)

[Running cURL on 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044010/running-curl-on-64-bit-windows)

and on GitHub:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4351

But got no success.
I also reinstalled the 'curl' in my machine and tried to use **Invoke-WebRequest** directly, but the problem persisted.

I'm new at PowerShell, maybe I'm doing a mistake when coding those lines, but do you have any suggestion how to deal with?
Do you think there is a better Command Prompt/CLI than PowerShell to use **curl**?

Comment: `curl` is a built-in alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.  Make sure you're calling `curl.exe`

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how can I check that? I typed `Get-Alias curl` and  it just confirmed the `Invoke-WebRequest`. Also tried to put `curl.exe` directly but got an error...

Comment: Post your error when you're trying to use `curl.exe`.  If I had to guess, you didn't qualify the path (i.e., you need to be in the directory where the executable is and call it like: `.\curl.exe ...`)

Comment: Nice! The error that I got now is `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cglcloud.jfrog.io`, but I think it's because I am behind a corporate proxy. Should I set the proxy in the same `.\curl.exe` line, correct?

Comment: I'm unsure how to use `curl.exe` and proxies, but I'm sure if you read the manpage for the utility then you can figure out which flags to pass.

Comment: No problem. I am going to checking on the curl website now...

Comment: It seems it worked, the only issue is the `protocol error`, as follows: `curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`. I'll take a look into it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Maximilian Burszley wrote, curl in PowerShell is an alias to another command, not the curl command you intended.

In my opinion the simplest solution is to remove the alias, and then the curl command will be available without the overhead of Get-Alias and without using curl with the executable's path.

This is the command to remove the curl alias when using Windows PowerShell:

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```