# Curl to a server with username and password protection

Tags: web-services, curl

I'm trying to use CURL on the following address (example)

```
https://examplesite.com/ExampleService/ExampleService.asmx?wsdl
```

When I copy the url to a browser i get the browser login popup and using the username and password i get to see the webservice XML file

But when i try to call curl to the same address using

```
curl -u username:password https://examplesite.com/ExampleService/ExampleService.asmx?wsdl
```

I get a 401 reply error.
What might be the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using curl with a username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

Comment: No it is not , did you read it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this website does not support the **basic authentication**.
That is the reason why you cannot log in by CURL.