# curl command line POST password

Tags: forms, post, curl, passwords

I have the following curl command which works perfectly fine:

```
curl --silent --location -cookie "$COOKIE" --cookie-jar "$COOKIE" \
--form 'username=xxx' --form 'password=yyy' 'http://example.com'
```

It logs into site http://example.com posting a form with variable names username and password.

Problem is: I do not want to pass the password in clear.

I have also tried to save the password in a file called passwd in the working directory (chmod 600 passwd) and used the following curl command (this is why I used --form instead of --data, which would have been worked fine with the password in clear), however, it does not work:

```
curl --silent --location -cookie "$COOKIE" --cookie-jar "$COOKIE" \
--form 'username=xxx' --form 'password=<passwd' 'http://example.com'
```

Any suggestion about how to solve this?

Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Z. answer to use environmental variable is correct in my opinion. Though I might just add that in bash you could use `read` command, which would prompt for password and not make it visible in history.

So the usage would look like this

```
$ read -s PASSWD  # -s is there so the characters you type don't show up
$ curl --silent --location -cookie "$COOKIE" --cookie-jar "$COOKIE" \
--form 'username=xxx' --form "password=${PASSWD}" 'http://example.com'
```

UPDATE:

Another solution found in the comments is to use `curl`'s `--data-urlencode name@filename` argument.
Quoting the manpage:

> name@filename
>   This will make curl load data from the given file (including any newlines),  URL-encode that data and pass it on in the POST.

And the final command looked like

```
$ curl --silent --location -cookie "$COOKIE" --cookie-jar "$COOKIE" \
--data 'username=xxx' --data-urlencode "password@passwd" 'http://example.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.

I forgot to metion that I would like to schedule the curl command in cron, so using an environmental variable would not help, because I do not want to put `export PASSWD=secret` in front of the cron command in the crontab file.

Comment: Why not make it something like this then?
`PASSWD=$(cat path-to-file-with-your-password); cron ... --form "password=$PASSWD" ...` (it's formatting badly, everything should be in one line)

Comment: @stx73 - you can set a permanent environmental variable, you don't have to do export every time.

Comment: It definitely works, however, I would consider the solution `--form 'password=<passwd'` more elegant, but it is not working now... should I add `;type=<mime type>`? Like `--form 'password=<passwd;type=<mime type>'`, and in case, which <mime type>?

I would like to make it working; adding `--trace-ascii -` to the curl command shows that the password is read from the _passwd_ file, but it does not work in the end.

Comment: It's weird it doesn't substitute the contents of a file. Maybe try this `curl --data-urlencode "password@passwd"`

Comment: Thanks @jakub, it works now: `curl --silent --location -cookie "$COOKIE" --cookie-jar "$COOKIE" --data 'username=xxx' --data-urlencode "password@passwd" 'http://example.com'` only thing, password in passwd must be stored _without_ '`\n`'...

Answer (score 0):

Set the password in an environment variable, e.g. `export PASSWD=secret` and use it in `--form "password=${PASSWD}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing secrets in command line is insecure as they are available in process list.

You should use the `--data-urlencode name@filename` approach

```
                 This will make curl load data from the given file
                 (including any newlines), URL-encode that data and
                 pass it on in the POST.
```

or  `-K, --config <file>`

```
          Specify a text file to read curl arguments from. The
          command line arguments found in the text file will be used
          as if they were provided on the command line.
```

See also [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45098231/1237617)