curl on Windows: How to pass a username and password to a POST form without putting the password in the command line or storing it in a file?
I want to automate downloading some files from a site that requires a login via a POST form using curl on Windows. I know how to pass form parameters, but this always seems to involve either typing the password in clear text on the command line, or storing it in a file. Both are no-nos. Is there a way to get curl to prompt me for the password that gets passed on to a form field via POST?
I haven't tried any of the options that would require me putting my password on the command line or in a file, and I am not aware of any other options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926736/curl-command-line-post-password gets close but still requires storing the password and it looks like it is for UNIX shells, but I am on Windows. Other than that, my approach is from CURL to access a page that requires a login from a different page

You can access environment variables as described here

You may use Powershell Invoke-WebRequest instead of curl to use Credentials variable such as $Cred1 = Get-Credential then $Invoke-Webrequest -Credential $Cred1

Thanks - with an environment variable, the password would still be exposed in clear text, wouldn't it?

Thanks for the PowerShell pointer @ErkinD39 - the credentials would be for a server login rather than a POST form field, wouldn't they? Compare https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#example-2-use-a-stateful-web-service

You may also find a POST example  for a similar powershell cmdlet Invoke-Restmethod at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4

As you say you are on windows: Be aware that the  curl command in Windows Powershell is typically an alias for Invoke-WebRequest unless you specifically installed curl

"the password would still be exposed in clear text"  exposed to whom? Yes, anybody who can access your machine can have a look at the environment  variables.

Given your constraints (the way I understand them), the only secure password will be the one you type in manually, in response to a prompt from curl like Password?>  (I don't know if that is possible so man curl is your friend). Good luck.

@user27676144 Yes -Credential parameter along with -Authentication parameter seems to be built for logging on, not for Form submitting. Submitting forms is usually accomplished via -Body parameter as seen in the examples - as you have pointed out the link.
