# How to encrypt password for cURL command in shell script. -u option cannot be used

Tags: security, unix, curl, passwords, parameter-passing

I am using cURL command in a shell script. If I use curl with `-u login:password` option, we can have access to these login and password as they are visible to anyone.

Is there  way to make password not clear in script file (or encrypt and decrypt it)?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894407/978414). This has nothing to do with encryption though.

Comment: Thanxx @igwan but my curl is included in a script and is accessing a url on artifactory

Comment: best practice would be to pass the credentials to your script like: sh script.sh USERNAME PASSWORD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cURL with a username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

Comment: @jwodder: the way the question is asked, i don't consider it a duplicate. it is not about how to pass credentials, it is about how to do it safely.

Comment: @TechnoFreak Did this solve your problem?

Comment: if you have the script user's public key, you can encrypt it with his public key, and make your script decrypt it on your user with his private key

Answer (score 1):

An example based on Base64:

```
curl -X GET -k -H 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdDpwYXNzd29yZA==' -i 'https://yoursite.com'
```

Base64 decoded: `test:password`

Base64 encoded: `dGVzdDpwYXNzd29yZA==`

Comment: well the base64 will still be available to anyone who can read `-u login:password` , so i don't think this actually helps much

Comment: Encoding is not Encrypting