# How to Login to an application using cURL?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I need to login to an application using cURL and find out the time taken to login to an application using cURL command.

What I have tried so far is write a shell script

curl -k -X -s "http://username:passowrd@servername:portnumber" -w 'Lookup time:\t%{time_namelookup} s

```
Total time:\t%{time_total} s
' -o /dev/null
```

IS this correct way to do it?

Comment: Related: [Using cURL with a username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2594880/1983854)

Comment: try: `time curl --user "username:password" --compressed "servername:portnumber"`