# curl command in git-bash

Tags: windows, bash, curl, git-bash

I have a script written in bash and tested working in Linux (CentOS 7) and on MacOS. The script uses `cURL` to interact with a REST API compliant data platform (XNAT).

I was hoping that Windows users could use the same script within git-bash that comes packaged with *Git for Windows*. Unfortunately there seems to be an issue when using `cURL` in git-bash.

The first use I make of `cURL` is to retrieve a JSESSION cookie:

```
COOKIE=`curl -k -u $USERNAME https://theaddress/JSESSION`
```

On Linux, this asks the user for password and stores the cookie in `COOKIE`.
In git-bash, issuing the command hangs, until using a "`ctrl + C`" to interrupt it. Strangely at that point the query message for the password is displayed, but too late, the script has terminated.

I have a suspicion that this may have to do with `CR` or `LF` issues, but cannot find some info I understand regarding this.

Any pointers would be welcome !

Thank you

**EDIT:**
It appears the above command works fine if I pass the password in the command like this:

```
COOKIE=`curl -k -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD https://theaddress/JSESSION`
```

However, as pointed here:
[Using cURL with a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)
I would rather avoid having the user typing their password as a command argument.

So the question is now "why is `cURL` not prompting for a password when I use the first command?" when in git-bash on Windows, while that command behaves as expected in Linux or MacOS:

```
 COOKIE=`curl -k -u $USERNAME https://theaddress/JSESSION`
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ending up replying to my own question, hope this may be useful to someone else.

It appears this issue is a known problem when running `cURL` from within git-bash, according to this thread:
https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/573

In particular, see the answer of **dscho** on *30 Dec 2015*:

> The problem is the terminal emulator we use with Git Bash since Git for Windows 2.5, MinTTY.
>   This terminal emulator is not associated with a Win32 Console, therefore the user does not see anything when cURL wants to interact with the user via said Console.

This issue has a workaround, which is documented here:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#known-issues

**The workaround is to run curl via winpty as follows:**
`winpty curl [arguments]`

Not an issue with `CR` or `LF` after all.

Soooo, git-bash may not be the *magic-bullet (tm)* to run my bash scripts in Windows with zero effort. Sigh...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bug link.... Such a shame the solution though.