# Passing user and password in URL doesn't work

Tags: html, http, curl, authentication, server

I have some URL like this : `X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080`

I tried to add a user and password in this url like this: `http://OLM:OLM794$@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080`

**User** = `OLM`

**Psw** = `OLM794$`

And it doesn't work

Also when I **run** : `curl http://OLM:OLM794$@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080` it shows me :

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host:OLM:OLM794X.XXX.XXX.XXX`, it removes `$@` and the port `:10080`

When I try : `curl -u OLM X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080` then I enter the password, it works, Im able to connecte to that server.

My need is to call my url with user and password like this:

```
http://OLM:OLM794$@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080
```

But it doesn't work.

I read this solution : [Using cURL with a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password) but I haven't found solution

Have you an idea why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cURL with a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

Comment: I have seen all tha solutions before ask a question, but it doesn't work !

Comment: Have you tried literally this (quotes and such)?  

`curl -u "OLM:OLM794$" "http://X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080"`
  
I usually see the error when a proxy (param `-x`) has to be set. This should not be the case if it sometimes works.

Comment: @Jan Molnar Yes it works with `" "` you can add your solution to accept it, I have an another issue maybe you have an idea, when I call this url in soap address location it doesn't work like this : `<soap:address location="http://'OLM:OLM794$'@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080"/>`

Comment: @PRINCE You cannot use single-quotes instead of double-quotes, I believe. See my answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem `curl` parses and reconstructs the URL, leaving out characters that it thinks are illegal. For me, the same command gives a different error though.. It could be that your curl version differs from mine.

```
$ curl -v http://OLM:OLM794$@127.0.0.1:10000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://OLM:OLM794127.0.0.1:10000/
* Port number ended with 'O'
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'O'
```

The solution is quite trivial, just url-escape the `$` symbol: `%24`:

```
$ curl http://OLM:OLM794%24@127.0.0.1:10000
```

---

According to [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), the dollar-sign was allowed as an unreserved character and could be directly used, but this old RFC has since been updated many times. [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3), for example, does not mention it as an unreserved character anymore. This means the `$` symbol has received a special meaning and should be encoded in any URL where it does not serve the function it was given.

Comment: Thanks @Jochem Kuijpers it works with `%24` or with `" "`,  `"OLM:OLM794$"@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080` like @Jan Molnar solution but now I facing to a new issue maybe you have an idea,  when I call this url in soap address location it doesn't work like this : `<soap:address location="http://'OLM:OLM794$'@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080"/>` also with ` when I call this url in soap address location it doesn't work like this : <soap:address location="http://OLM:OLM794%24@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080"/>`

Comment: @PRINCE Don't escape the credentials with single-quotes. Instead, just url-encode them. 
`<soap:address location="http://OLM:OLM794%24@X.XXX.XXX.XXX:10080"/>` should work. If that does not work, consider changing the password so it does not include an illegal URL character or see if you can use a better authentication method.

Comment: In curl it works  as your solution `%24` but in my soap:address, It doesn't

Comment: Okey, I accept the answer because the question is about `curl` thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is related to whatever code is handling the URL in the XML. If so, I recommend you post it as a new question.