# Solace Rest API usage or samples other than CURL Post sample in the documentation

Tags: solace

I am trying to construct a map object with relevant parameters to send a message using POST URL via REST. Looks like the cURL command line tool with the parameters work perfectly fine in posting a message into Solace Persistent queue. However, when I  construct the parameters like User ID, Pwd, VPN URL, Queue name, message in a map object, the Solace VPN always rejects saying invalid credentials. Are there any samples available from Solace on the construction of map object with these parameters? In the current documentation, we have only the cURL command sample is given. Kindly advise if anyone has solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to the example cURL commands for Solace REST messaging here:
https://docs.solace.com/RESTMessagingPrtl/Solace-REST-Example.htm

To add credentials information for cURL, you just need the "-u" flag as described here:
[Using cURL with a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The curl command line sample in the documentation works perfectly fine with all the relevant flags. My problem is when I have to convert the relevant parameters into a map object before posting the URL request. I am doing it in a third party application which supports REST API calls.

Comment: Can you share any relevant code excerpts of what you are trying in this third party app?

Comment: Thanks, the issue with the credentials map and headers is sorted out. Now the connectivity is perfectly fine.