# Install RPM package from Artifactory

Tags: linux, artifactory, rpm

I am trying to install rpm package in linux, and the package is stored in artifactory.

command I used:

```
rpm -ihv --nodeps --force https:/artifactory.com/myrpm.rpm
```

I got 'transfer failed' error message, and this is expected because the artifactory website requires authentication. (username/password).

Found one thing that there is a command 'curl'. How to utilize this command if this is the right solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try passing username and password in the URL as per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/371918):

```
$ rpm -ihv --nodeps --force https://<username>:<password>@artifactory.com/myrpm.rpm
```

The steps to do it with curl would be as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594908/1602555):

```
$ curl -u <username>:<password> https://artifactory.com/myrpm.rpm
$ rpm -ihv --nodeps ./myrpm.rpm
```