# Using cURL to download a dropbox link which is protected with password

Tags: curl, dropbox

I added a shared link to a dropbox file, and set the link settings to allow access to 'anyone with link'.

I use the following cURL syntax to successfully download the file from Dropbox

```
curl -L -o myFile.txt https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou....8/myFile.txt?dl=0
```

I would like to change the link settings to add a password to the link, and allow access to 'anyone with link and password'

Is there a way of specifying the password as part of the cURL syntax?

I note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password) which is similar, but I do not think it is relevant for me as Dropbox uses its own customized password entry screen.

[image]

The name of the link password text-box in the DOM is "shared-link-password" and I experimented - unsuccessfully - with adding `-F shared-link-password=mypassword` to the cURL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately Dropbox doesn't offer a way to supply a shared link's password as a parameter like this, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

The supported parameters are documented here:

https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download

Those only enable you to modify how the data is returned; it doesn't cover supplying a password.