# How to specify @ in username and password for curl command?

Tags: json, linux, rest, curl

```
$ curl -k -i -X POST -d '{ "path" : "/" }' https://abc@example.com:qwer@@53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com:33001/files/workspaces/42796/all/12345:2
```

results in:

```
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'I'
```

Without @:

```
$ curl -k -i -X POST -d '{ "path" : "/" }' https://abcexample.com:qwer@53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com:33001/files/workspaces/42796/all/12345:2
```

results in:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com port 33001: Connection timed out
```

**How to specify @ in username and password for curl command?**

Comment: Put the url in quotes

Comment: `$ curl -k -i -X POST -d '{ "path" : "/" }' "https://abc@example.com":qwer@@53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com:33001/files/workspaces/42796/all/12345:2`  This asks for password and then shows the same error.

Comment: I mean the complete URL and so :"https:\/\/abc@example.com:qwer@@53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com:33001/files/workspaces/42796/all/12345:2"

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594908/1866530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the auth username or password contain an `@` symbol, it should be urlencoded to %40.

Your curl command could look like either of these examples:

```
curl -k -i -X POST -d '{ "path" : "/" }' \ 
  https://abc%40example.com:qwer%40@53096wrxgcg.ibmaspera.com:33001/files/workspaces/42796/all/12345:2
```

or

```
curl --user abc%40example.com:qwer%40 -k -i ...
```