# Encrypting credentials

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I am using *curl - u user:password -X post* method in shell script to trigger my Jenkins jobs externally. While using this method I am providing my credentials to access Jenkins.
Is there any way to hide or encrypt credentials.?

Comment: https://programming.vip/docs/use-a-curl-with-a-username-and-password.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password/27894407#27894407 

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205479/is-it-insecure-to-send-a-password-in-a-curl-command

Answer (score 1):

Curl with `-u` does not support encrypt username and password but you can do it in different way to hide username and password

1. Create an environment variable Use that on your curl command like below :

```
export USERNAME=""
export PASSWORD=""
```

after that

```
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X POST ...
```

2. Make use of .netrc file with curl command.

curl command option for .netrc file

```
-n, --netrc         Must read .netrc for user name and password
    --netrc-file <filename> Specify FILE for netrc
```

Steps to use .netrc

1. Create a .netrc file on your home directory (~) with content

```
machine jenkins.url
login username
password jenkinsTokenOrPassword
```

2. invoke curl command

```
curl -n -X POST ....
```

Note. If you don't want to keep your .netrc file on your home directory `~` , than place it somewhere else but make sure let curl know about the location like `curl --netrc-file /path/to/.netrc -X POST ...`